# I cant figure out what is wrong with my loop. Im still new to python but I swear this has worked in the past

Tags: python

I am trying to finish up this assignment for school but cant figure out how to do it. The problem I am having is the for loop.  It keeps returning *invalid syntax*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import stats
T = 1
r=0.06
m=0.03
mu = r-m
sigma = 0.2
H=99
S0 = 100
M=100
N =10
dt = T/N
t = np.linspace(0, T, N)
W = np.random.standard_normal(size = N) 
W = np.cumsum(W)*np.sqrt(dt) ### standard brownian motion ###
X = (mu-0.5*sigma**2)*t + sigma*W 
S = S0*np.exp(X) ### geometric brownian motion ###
i = 1
j=100
while S >= H
    if True
        S = S*np.exp(X)
        i += 1
    if False
        print(" Barrier crossed at ",i)
        break
    elif 
        print("error")
        break   

plt.plot(t, S)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Doesn't python require a `:` at the end of the line for loops and conditionals?

Comment: @leaf: IMO that tag is not that useful. Feel free to add it back.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all `if False` will never evaluate the way you want it to, `False` is always false.

You also need to finish your while loop statement and all of your conditional statements with a colon (`:`), that's why you're getting a syntax error. Also, your `elif` doesn't have a condition to evaluate, so that's going to throw another syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

#### CODE REVIEW

Start by fixing the invalid syntax by adding a semicolon `:` at the end of the while loop statement. Still, your code won't be able to evaluate the while. You can end with an error like *the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous*.

Basically, if you print the condition `print(S >= H)`
You will get an array `[False True False True True True True True True True]`

You could assign the expression to a variable like `array = S >= H` 
 Which you might want to evaluate with something like `while array.all():` or `while array.any():`

Now, `array.all()` will result in `False`, and anything under the while won't be evaluated/executed, at the end the plot will show up.

If you decide to try `array.any()` if will result in `True` and everything inside the loop will be evaluated.

To make it work you would have to correct more syntax issues. After each if statement add the semicolon and add a condition after the elif and don't forget the semicolon.

Now, the block under `if False:` won't be evaluated, because **always is False**. The block under `if True:` will be always evaluated because **always is True**. Anyway, the result will be staying in the loop forever making the operation and the plot won't show up.